# Mac shortcuts to run commands in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am getting started with using the Sypder IDE for Python.

What is the mac shortcut to run the entire script and run the selected lines in Sypder?

The windows shortcut for the same are -

```
F5* executes the current file.

F9* executes the currently highlighted chunk of code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fn + F5 and fn + f9 keys to be used for mac usage of the above commands.